# User login required accessing SharePoint 2010 inside network with SSL

Tags: sharepoint-2010

we have a sharepoint 2010 site and are using the same url to access it from inside and outside the network.

our issue is that we don't want users inside our network to get asked for credentials when accessing the site.

if, for example, the url we wanted to use was https://sp.domain.com, how would we set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via Alternate Access mappings. Have two zones for your sharepoint site: Intranet and Extranet. In AAM settings:

1. Intranet : http://sp.domain.com
2. Extranet: http://extranet.domain.com

You did not specify which authentication scheme if you are using for outside network. If its forms authentication, you can set Windows for 1 and Forms authentication for 2.

However, if its AD only for both, you will have to have sp.domain.com configured as Intranet Url and extranet.domain.com as Internet Url in each of client computer. This can be done using  group policy.

Your proxy server will have to do the work of transferring the sp.domain.com from external network to extranet.domain.com internally.

Good to read:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=804

Comment: thanks for the tip madhur - we're using active directory for both, so we'll have to use the group policy method. i was thinking that there was perhaps a way to do it other than group policy modifications, but i guess not.